# Remove a List of characters from another List

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a list that contains characters  = | ( )  scattered throughout that i want to remove. the problem is the characters do not fall into a list element. They are part of a list element. I tried replace but it doesnt take a List[]. escaping each characters with a backslash but it doent work either. not sure whats the right syntax.  any suggestions?

```
alst = ['2', 'TEAM', '=', '27.92', '4', '0', '0', '20.25(', '18)', '0', '0', '0 |', '1', '0', '0 |', '27.03', '2 |', '28.55', '2 |', '28.35', '2', '(region west)']

removelst = ['=', '|', '(', ')']

endresult  = ['2', 'TEAM', '', '27.92', '4', '0', '0', '20.25', '18', '0', '0', '0 ', '1', '0', '0 ', '27.03', '2 ', '28.55', '2 ', '28.35', '2', 'region west']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Geeks for Geeks: Python | Removing unwanted characters from string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-removing-unwanted-characters-from-string/) (I just googled "python remove chars from string"):

```
def clean(s):
    return ''.join(i for i in s if not i in removelst)
endresult = [clean(s) for s in alst]
```

I wouldn't introduce regex for this - not necessary, since it's doable in a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sanitize(s, bad_chars):
    for c in bad_chars:
        s = s.replace(c, '')
    return s


def sanitize_list(l, bad_chars):
    return [sanitize(item, bad_chars) for item in l]


alst = ['2', 'TEAM', '=', '27.92', '4', '0', '0', '20.25(', '18)', '0', '0', '0 |', '1', '0', '0 |', '27.03', '2 |', '28.55', '2 |', '28.35', '2', '(region west)']
removelst = ['=', '|', '(', ')']
endresult = sanitize_list(alst, removelst)
```

Comment: thanks jc, it works. but i was wondering if there was a easier way to do this instead of 2 functions... any python 'magic' that reduces this to a list comprehension or nested LC?